# Can one be arrested for viewing adult sites while in the UAE?

Tags: legal, uae, sex

Does the police in UAE arrest people for accessing adult internet sites?

Comment: Well it would appear to be [illegal](http://sahrzad.net/blog/is-it-safe-to-surf-adults-only-sites-in-gulf-countries-uae-saudi-arabia-oman-bahrain-qatar-etc/),so, yeah.

Comment: @MarkMayo Speeding is illegal in most places but you'd be unlikely to be arrested for it, at least in the UK and US (AFAIK).

Comment: @DavidRicherby true, most of the time.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Privateinternetaccess.com](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/blog/2016/07/use-vpn-bypass-voip-ban-uae-get-fined-544k/):

> At the current USD exchange rate, that translates to a potential $544521.48 fine.
>
> Currently, such crimes include accessing blocked services or websites, which can only be done with a VPN or proxy, use that the UAE considers fraudulent use of an IP address. That means watching pornography (a worry for tourists)

So yeah. Porn is blocked if you go around the block that's a crime and you can be fined up to half a million USD.

Comment: I am not much computer literate..do not know much about VPN and proxy,does that apply to desk tops,tablets, laptops.what of the simple mobile phone 3g network..in my country i have accessed a blocked site on my cellphone but not on the computer how does that work if the site is blocked aleady.

Comment: @chx Fortunately the UAE's filter is pretty rudimentary and it's not too hard to find unblocked content.

Comment: I mean... they'd have to actively find you watching porn, otherwise how could they even arrest or fine you?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55900/discussion-on-answer-by-chx-can-one-be-arrested-for-viewing-adult-sites-whilst-i).